# Warning while importing JEdit from SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, jedit

I am trying to make some modifications to JEdit which is stored using SVN (Its a project).
I have installed TortoiseSVN and got the files from the server into my pc.
Then I imported the files as a existing project into Eclipse.

The problem now is that it gives me the following warnings when I compile and run it.

> 1:15:26 PM [main] [warning] jEdit: jedit.jar not in class path!
>
> 1:15:26 PM [main] [warning] jEdit: Assuming jEdit is installed in E:\College\SEProj\jEdit.
>
> 1:15:26 PM [main] [warning] jEdit: Override with jedit.home system property.
>
> 1:15:26 PM [main] [warning] jEdit: initPLAF failed to set required l&f
>
> 1:15:26 PM [main] [warning] jEdit: initPLAF failed to set required l&f

And It also gives an Error 'The project cannot be built until build parts are resolved.'
(I was able to solve this error by importing all the jar files, due to some reason, I also had to import tools.jar)

Whatever changes I make in the source code, makes no changes at compile time. I even tried to delete an entire class and still there was no change in execution. Is it due to this? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is assuming it is installed in `E:\College\SEProj\jEdit`. You need to override the `jedit.home` system property to point to your eclipse project directory, as the messages say.

Answer (score 0):

jEdit builds with ant and requires that you configure the build.properties file to point to various dependencies on your system. A sample called `build.properties.sample` is in the root of trunk.

Read the `README.SRC.txt` file - its also in the root of jEdit trunk - which describes how to build jEdit, including special tips (line:178) for IDE users (i.e. Eclipse etc).

Personally, I'm building jEdit on a mac running 10.8.5 in Intellij 12.1.5. I would think any IDE with support for ANT (most) should be ok. I've not tried in Eclipse though.

Comment: No, I have not, though I am able to edit now after correcting the libraries. Still can you tell me the steps to achieve no warnings

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more details which I hope help. If you still have warnings that are preventing you from building post them. If I tell you steps without knowing the problem who knows where you will end up ;)